# MyBatis-Spring ManagedTransactionFactory Exception

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-transactions

I use Mybatis-Spring with jta-transaction-manager but get "Sqlsessionfactory must be using a springmanagedtransactionfactory in order to use Spring transaction synchronization" exception. I look into Mybatis-Spring source code and find that MybatisExceptionTranslator > initExceptionTranslator function use spring.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils > doGetConnection to get sql error codes and bind datasource to transaction synchronization manager then if you use this datasource in current thread again, get this exception.

Mybatis/spring -> MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java > initExceptionTranslator()

```
private synchronized void initExceptionTranslator() {
  if(this.exceptionTranslator == null) {
     this.exceptionTranslator = new SQLErrorCodesExceptionTranslator(this.datasource);
  }
}
```

mybatis/spring -> SqlSessionUtils.java > registerSessionHolder

```
if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(environment.getDataSource()) == null) {
     LOGGER.debug(() -> "SqlSession [" + session
                  + "] was not registered for synchronization because DataSource is not transactional");
} else {
    throw new TransientDataAccessResourceException(
                  "SqlSessionFactory must be using a SpringManagedTransactionFactory in order to use Spring transaction synchronization");
}
```

**Mybatis Datasource transactionfactory:**

```
<property name="transactionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransactionFactory" />
</property>
```

**My Spring Data Config:**

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

Comment: You should consider providing a repro. In addition to a small repro project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues), we may need the details about your setup (db, container, etc.; docker-compose.xml might be better).